# Vim command line argument not being executed

Tags: linux, bash, vim, calendar

I've been looking for a command line calendar program for Linux for quite some time now. I realized I should just use vim. I want to be able to easily view a week of todo lists. Currently using this command:

```
data=$(unset split; echo -n "-c \""; for i in {6..0}; do if [ $i -ne 6 ] ; then split="vsplit"; else split="e"; fi; echo -n "$split $(date +"%F" -d"last sunday+$i day").txt|"; done; echo "\"") && precmd='-c "split todo.txt" -c "Calendar" -c "wincmd w"' && cmd="vim $precmd $data" && eval $cmd
```

Run this in a full screen terminal, otherwise you're gonna have a bad time. Requires this calendar plugin: https://github.com/mattn/calendar-vim 
If you don't have the vim calendar plugin, this will work too but it won't have the calendar:

```
data=$(unset split; echo -n "-c \""; for i in {6..0}; do if [ $i -ne 6 ] ; then split="vsplit"; else split="e"; fi; echo -n "$split $(date +"%F" -d"last sunday+$i day").txt|"; done; echo "\"") && precmd='-c "split todo.txt"' && cmd="vim $precmd $data" && eval $cmd
```

This does exactly what I want, except that the lower pane does not load my rolling todo.txt. If I could just get that lower pane to load my todo.txt, I would be all set! I can't figure out why vim won't accept my:

```
-c "split todo.txt"
```

Feel free to correct my horrendous bash as well.

Also, I do realize that the vim calendar plugin has a "diary" feature, but AFAIK it doesn't split the window as I require.

Thanks!

Edit: Here is an updated version which fixes an issue when run on Sundays, and also allows you to specify the week offset, ie, "vimcal 0" "vimcal 1" "vimcal -1" etc. (Of course you will need to create a script and/or alias)

```
data=$(unset split; unset day; echo -n "-c \""; for i in {6..0}; do if [ $i -ne 6 ] ; then split="vsplit"; else split="split"; fi; if [ `date +"%A"` = "Sunday" ] ; then day="sunday"; else day="last sunday"; fi; echo -n "$split $(date +"%F" -d"$day+$i day+$1 week").txt|"; done; echo "\"") && precmd='-c "edit todo.txt" -c "Calendar" -c "wincmd w"' && cd ~/Documents/todo && cmd="vim $precmd $data" && eval $cmd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim *does* execute the `:split todo.txt`; you'll see the (hidden) file in the output of `:ls!`. The problem becomes apparent when you print the executed command line (by replacing `eval` with `echo`):

```
vim -c "split todo.txt" -c "e 2013-10-05.txt|vsplit 2013-10-04.txt|vsplit 2013-10-03.txt|vsplit 2013-10-02.txt|vsplit 2013-10-01.txt|vsplit 2013-09-30.txt|vsplit 2013-09-29.txt|"
```

From the default empty buffer, you `:split` off the todo.txt file, and then, in that same window `:edit` the first dated file. You need to swap the two opening commands, like this:

```
data=$(unset split; echo -n "-c \""; for i in {6..0}; do if [ $i -ne 6 ] ; then split="vsplit"; else split="split"; fi; echo -n "$split $(date +"%F" -d"last sunday+$i day").txt|"; done; echo "\"") && precmd='-c "edit todo.txt"' && cmd="vim $precmd $data" && eval $cmd
```

Comment: Awesome! :D It works perfectly, thank you for your help!